# Cannot get the appropriate histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm working on credit card data available on Kaggle. I want to plot the histogram for a column named 'Amount' from the data file named 'credit'. I want the plot for all the range of Amount but I ain't getting it. The range of Amount is [0,25691.16]. But the range showing in the plot is max_value/(num_bins). What should be the change in the code required to get plot over the total range mentioned above?

In the example code mentioned below the plot is showing a single bar of width 2569.116 (range/num_bins). What I need is 10 bars covering the entire range

```
plt.hist(credit['Amount'],10,density=True,range=(0,25691.16) ,facecolor='red',alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: Using a different dataframe, and an appropriate range, your code snippet worked fine for me.  Can you expand on which Credit Card data you are using for your dataframe?

Comment: Credit card data to find fraudulent transactions. I found it on kaggle. The data is a 31×284646 matrix

Answer (score 1):

your code is right. I think it is the nature of your data that you cannot see the other bars since the density in the first bin is very high. In other words, almost all 'Amount' are in (0, 2569.116) and there are a few 'Amount' that are in the intervals (2569.116, 5138.232), ... , (23122.044, 25691.16).

Comment: I just went through the excel data carefully and found most of the lies in the range of 2.5k range. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi @MonkeyDLuffy. Since you thought the answer is correct, please upvote it and mark is as the correct answer by clicking on the green check mark on the left side of the answer.